# Загрузка файла Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Есть `api` и `web` интерфейсы в одном проекте Laravel. Делаю запрос к api на получение файла, код обработки api:

```
$file = Storage::disk('local')->path('private/1r3Z6GxxedXtZPViLGTRUZHehF1IiYZQRgIhZxC1.jpeg');
return response()->download($file);
```

Как мне правильно обработать файл на стороне клиента, или правильно его вернуть с `api` (при моём коде выводится какой-то текст, напоминающий xml и байтовую строку):

```
$resp = $this->sendApiRequest(false, [], '/library/download');
return $resp;
```

Comment: Используйте `blob`

Comment: @doox911 Можно примеры или ссылки, на `php.net`, `laravel/api` ничего толкового не нашёл.